# enable_if to Add a function parameter that has a default argument?

Tags: c++, sfinae, enable-if

I can't understand the second scenario presented [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee361639.aspx). It says:

> •Scenario 2: Adding a function parameter that has a default argument:

```
template <your_stuff> your_return_type_if_present
yourfunction(args, enable_if_t<your condition, FOO> = BAR) {
    // ...
}
```

> Scenario 2 leaves the parameter unnamed. You could say `::type Dummy = BAR`, but the name *Dummy* is irrelevant, and giving it a name is likely to trigger an *unreferenced parameter* warning. You have to choose a `FOO` function parameter type and `BAR` default argument. You could say `int` and `0`, but then users of your code could accidentally pass to the function an extra integer that would be ignored. Instead, we recommend that you use `void **` and either `0` or `nullptr` because almost nothing is convertible to `void **`:

```
template <your_stuff> your_return_type_if_present 
yourfunction(args, typename enable_if<your_condition, void **>::type=nullptr) {
 // ...
}
```

If scenario 2 leaves the parameter unnamed then in what can it be used?
Is there a way to make a code like this work with `enable_if`?

```
enum otype {oadd,omull};
template<otype o>
int add(int num1, std::enable_if<o == oadd, int>::type int= num2)
{
    if (o == omull) return num1 * num1;
    if (o == oadd ) return num1 + num2;
 }
```

Comment: It can be useful when (ab)using overload resolution for example.

Comment: the `omull` part cannot be reached.

Comment: enable_if enables the function, not the parameter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`enable_if` examples (if it helps):

**For functions with non-void return type:**

*For single condition:*

```
template <template T, typename std::enable_if<!std::is_same<T,std::string>::value>::type* = nullptr >
T func(T x){}
```

*For multiple condition:*

```
template <template T, typename std::enable_if<!std::is_same<T,std::string>::value &&!std::is_same<T,int>::value>::type* = nullptr >
T func(T x){}
```

---

**For functions with void return type:**

*For single condition:*

```
template <template T>
typename std::enable_if<!std::is_same<T,std::string>::value>::type
func(T x){}
```

*For multiple condition:*

```
template <template T>
typename std::enable_if<!std::is_same<T,std::string>::value &&!std::is_same<T,int>::value>::type
func(T x){}
```

Don't forget to include `#include <type_traits>`

Answer (score 11):

Microsoft's documentation [there](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee361639.aspx)
there is as clear as mud. Use [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if) instead.

Providing a function template with an unnamed default parameter of the form:

```
typename enable_if<your_condition, void **>::type = nullptr
```

(as the MS scribe suggests), is useful in case - and only in case - you wish
to write multiple overloads of the function template with different behaviours
that are controlled by one or more of the template arguments. Then, by
replacing `your_condition` with a condition expressing an appropriate
requirement on the template argument(s), you can enlist the [SFINAE](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae)
principle to select the specific overload that you want to be instantiated for
given template arguments.

The SFINAE parameter - let's call it that - is
unused by the instantiated function; it exists solely to provoke SFINAE in function template
overload resolution. Hence it can be nameless, and hence it must be defaulted:
it must not force you to provide an additional, useless, argument when you
invoke the function template.

For example:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
T foo(T && t, 
    typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<T,int>::value, void **>::type = nullptr)
{
    std::cout << "Doubling " << t << " gives " << (t + t) << std::endl;
    return t + t; 
}

template <typename T>
T foo(T && t, 
    typename std::enable_if<!std::is_same<T,int>::value, void **>::type = nullptr)
{
    std::cout << "Squaring " << t << " gives " << (t * t) << std::endl;
    return t * t; 
}

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << foo(2) << endl;
    cout << foo(3.3) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output is:

```
Doubling 2 gives 4
4
Squaring 3.3 gives 10.89
10.89
```

In these two overloads of function template `foo`, the first one doubles it's
type `T` argument and the second one squares its argument, and a SFINAE
parameter is used to determine that the doubling overload will be instantiated
if `T` is `int` and that the squaring overload will be chosen otherwise.

When `T` is `int`, the condition:

```
!std::is_same<T,int>::value
```

that controls the SFINAE parameter of the squaring overload is false. Consequently
the type specifier:

```
typename std::enable_if<!std::is_same<T,int>::value, void **>::type = nullptr
```

fails to compile. That is a *substitution failure* in template resolution. Substituting
`int` for `T` in the squaring overload is *not viable*. So the squaring overload is 
eliminated from the running, and only the doubling overload is left to instantiate 
the function call.

When `T` is (say) `double` and not `int`, then exactly the opposite happens
and only the squaring overload survives template resolution. Call `foo(2)`
and you get doubling. Call `foo(3.3)` and you get squaring.

MS's specimen SFINAE parameter here is needlessly lengthy.

```
template< bool B, class T = void >
struct enable_if;
```

as per C++11 Standard and later, defaults `T` to `void`. So the like of:

```
typename std::enable_if<some_condition, void **>::type = nullptr
```

can as well be abbreviated to:

```
typename std::enable_if<some_condition>::type * = nullptr
```

And as of C++14 the Standard has:

```
template< bool B, class T = void >
using enable_if_t = typename enable_if<B,T>::type
```

So the same SFINAE parameter can be further shortened to:

```
std::enable_if_t<some_condition> * = nullptr
```

Applying a SFINAE function template parameter to the case that you have gestured at in your
post, you would write the like of:

```
enum ops {
    add,
    multiply
};

template<ops Op>
int op(int const & lhs, int const & rhs, 
        std::enable_if_t<Op == add> * = nullptr)
{
    return lhs + rhs;
}

template<ops Op>
int op(int const & lhs, int const & rhs, 
        std::enable_if_t<Op == multiply> * = nullptr)
{
    return lhs * rhs;
}

...

auto i = op<add>(2,3);
auto j = op<multiply>(2,3);

...
// C++14
```

Comment: Thank you! I finally found a clear explanation about using `enable_if` for SFINAE. Your answer let me learn a lot! The abbreviations all the way to `std::enable_if_t<some_condition> * = nullptr` is really helpful! I want to ask that why abbreviate `void **` to `std::enable_if<some_condition>::type *`, which the latter one I think is in fact `void *`? Appreciate it in advanced.